# Google Maps API accessible with Java, Python or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-maps

Is there a way anyone knows to call the Google Maps APIs from Ruby for example?

Comment: You can start [here](https://github.com/edwardsamuel/google-maps-services-ruby/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: i might share working rails code from a real project - but it has limited functionality, just shows the place in a map as a picture file, and opens a map modal when clicked on it.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write a tutorial and code for you.

Comment: @marmeladze Thanks that would be great. That's exactly what I am working on, and I don't want to put my key in the client js so I thought I could do the call to the API on the server using Ruby.

Comment: follow that 3 links

[1] https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/9dec4c0536def82b65c62334430eca16

[2] https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/cb5c5aa40b6cf96942228319c5dec2d6

[3] https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/9c0a173803e305a7079ce6eef5190761

Answer (score 1):

With a key, you can access the APIs through simple HTTPS requests, which you can send using `open-uri` and parse using `json`.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'ostruct'
require 'json'

def journey_between start, destination
  key = "[Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/web/ to get a free key]"

  url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=#{start}&destinations=#{destination}&key=#{key}"

  json_response = open(url).read
  journey_data = JSON.parse(json_response, object_class: OpenStruct).rows[0].elements[0]
  return journey_data
end

journey = journey_between "London", "Glasgow"

puts journey.distance.text
#=> "412 mi"

puts journey.duration.text
#=> "6 hours 46 mins"
```

Unfortunately, you can't try this example without an API key. You can get one at https://developers.google.com/maps/web/ for free by registering a project under your Google account.

Comment: The question is off-topic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing are applicable.